# Error: ERR.SP.BUSINESS_ERROR while sending CreatePassengerNameRecordRS request at Sabre

Tags: soap, sabre, sabredav

While sending request CreatePassengerNameRecordRS to create PNR on sabre, receiving an error "ERR.SP.BUSINESS_ERROR" which describe "Could not find the PNR locator in the End Transaction response".
What is the root cause for this error?

````
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[code] => ERR.SP.BUSINESS_ERROR
[content] => PNR has not been created successfully, see remaining messages for details
)
[1] => stdClass Object
(
[code] => ERR.SP.BUSINESS_ERROR
[content] => Could not find the PNR locator in the End Transaction response
)
)```
````

Comment: Would you mind to share your request object (CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ) ? The root cause of this error is gonna to depends the way you are creating your reservation. Is it only 1 Pax ? Do you have any CHD or INF in your reservation ? are you adding any DOCS or DOCO ? It will be easier if you share your RQ

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is that something in the creation of the PNR didn't go through, maybe some mandatory fields in the PNR were missing and the service is not able to save the record locator by ending the transaction, thus it returns this warning.